# Return of printf with non printable characters

Tags: c

For a school project I have to record the function `printf`, and actually I have an issue with the return of `printf`.

Here what I try:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF-8");

printf("%d\n", printf("%C", L'猫'));
printf("%d\n", printf("%C", L'요'));
printf("%d\n", printf("%c", 0));

printf("\n--------------\n\n");

printf("%d\n",ft_printf("%C", L'猫'));
printf("%d\n",ft_printf("%C", L'요'));
printf("%d\n",ft_printf("%c", 0));
```

Here the result with ./a.out

```
猫3

요3

1

--------------

猫3

요3

1
```

But when i do it with `cat -e`:

```
�M-^L��M-^ZM-^T^@^@^@�M-^L�3$

�M-^ZM-^T3$

^@1$

--------------$


3$

3$

1$
```

And I don't understand how to get such result.

Comment: `%C` is not a format specifier in the standard, for printing a single character it's `%c`

Comment: and for printing *wide* characters the specifier is `%lc` - since you are using the wrong specifier your code has *undefined behavior*

Comment: What is `ft_printf`? And, can you repeat your question?

Comment: @Pablo ft_printf is the function printf I did myself and my question is that i get the same result when i just execute the function but in reality it's not the exact same behaviour as you can see when i cat -e because the real printf is writing for exemple for 0 -> ˆ@

Comment: @UnholySheep %C is the same as %lc

Comment: No, it is not. `%C` is not defined in the C standard - it must be a compiler extension (so you need to specify which compiler you are using).

Comment: @Shenron ah, you mean you mean that on the recorded file using `ft_printf` doesn't show the multibyte characters? Well, show us your `ft_printf` method then. And how do you record the output? A simple redirection `./a.out > file.txt` perhaps?

Comment: ➜  ~ cat test.txt
猫요猫3
요3
1

--------------

3
3
1

Comment: @Shenron no I mean, how did you create `test.txt`?

Comment: i am just doing as you said with redirecting ./a.out > file.txt